# AngularJS - TypeError while accessing JS object name/value pair of an service object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Why is the expression `databaseService[user1Constant].accountBalance` producing the error below?

`angularJsApplicationController.js`:

```
app.controller("angularJsController", function ($scope, $location, $http, user1Constant, user2Constant, databaseService) {
    databaseService[user1Constant+'Request'].done(function(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(databaseService));
        console.log(user1Constant);
        console.log(databaseService);
        console.log(databaseService[user1Constant]);
        console.log(databaseService[user1Constant].accountBalance);
    });
});
```

[image]

This is the code where I create the object:
`angularJsApplication.js`:

```
app.service("databaseService", ["user1Constant","user2Constant", function (user1Constant, user2Constant) {
    var returnObject = {};
    returnObject.updateAllEntriesUser = function (user) {

        //jQuery AJAX HTTP method
        $.post("getEntriesFromUser.php", {
            user: user
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                returnObject[user]={};
                returnObject[user].bookings = response;
                var totalAmount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    totalAmount += parseFloat(response[i].amount_before_comma + '.' + response[i].amount_after_comma);
                }
                returnObject[user].accountBalance = totalAmount;
            });
    };
    returnObject[user1Constant + 'Request'] = returnObject.updateAllEntriesUser(user1Constant);
    returnObject[user1Constant + 'Request'] = returnObject.updateAllEntriesUser(user2Constant);
    return returnObject;
}]);
```

Comment: your `databaseService` service does not have the object. can you add database service file content?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg the returnObject and the databaseService object are equal

Comment: The console will show the object as it is currently, not when you called `console.log`. If `databaseService` is being filled asynchronously, it's possible the data isn't there when you ask for it.

Comment: @spongessuck What do you mean with "as it is curently". So the shown object when the `console.log` statement is executed is from another moment?

Comment: @spongessuck Furthemore how can I wait in AngularJS with the execution of the controller until the service object (especially the ajax request) is done.

Comment: @d4rty Exactly, it's showing the current state of the object. If you're using the `$http` service, you should store the request in a property on `databaseService`, i.e. `this.data = $http.get(...)` and then you can call `databaseService.data.success(function() { ...` and then get the user data, since the `$http` service will call the function passed to `success` when the data is resolved without an error.

Comment: @spongessuck But the current state is the desired one, there is nothing which isn't already loaded inside the object. (everything I loaded via AJAX is in the `console.log` statement). More over I didn't get the point where (Service/Controller) I have to wait for the AJAX request (see updated question).

Comment: Why are you doing jQuery requests having AngularJS? check the $http service or Restangular plugin and use promises. It will be better integrated with angular. Anyway, your databaseService keys are "user1Constant + 'Request'" and you are trying to access them as "user1Constant", it looks like you are missing the 'Request' part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is showing you the object state as it is currently after the request is complete, which isn't what it looks like when you write it to the console. Your controller is trying to access the data before it's loaded, which is why your user data doesn't have the properties you expect it to.

You need to return a jQuery deferred object from your service and then pass a function to its `done` function so that you can wait to get the data until it's loaded.

Or you could cheat and use $scope.$watch...

You could change it to be more flexible, but to get it to work with the least amount of changes:

```
app.service("databaseService", ["user1Constant","user2Constant", function (user1Constant, user2Constant) {
  var returnObject = {};
  returnObject.updateAllEntriesUser = function (user) {

    //jQuery AJAX HTTP method
    return $.post("getEntriesFromUser.php", {
        user: user
    })
        .done(function (response) {            
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            returnObject[user]={};
            returnObject[user].bookings = response;
            var totalAmount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                totalAmount += parseFloat(response[i].amount_before_comma + '.' + response[i].amount_after_comma);
            }
            returnObject[user].accountBalance = totalAmount;
        });
  }

  returnObject[user1Constant + 'Request'] = returnObject.updateAllEntriesUser(user1Constant);
  returnObject[user2Constant + 'Request'] = returnObject.updateAllEntriesUser(user2Constant);
  console.log(returnObject); //angularJsApplication.js:101
  return returnObject;
});
```

And your controller:

```
app.controller("angularJsController", function ($scope, $location, $http, user1Constant, user2Constant, databaseService) {
    databaseService[user1Constant + 'Request'].done(function() {
        /* Now I can get databaseService[user1Constant] */
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. I applied your solution but now I get the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined**, when I do the `console.log[user1Constant].accountBalance` statement inside the controller `.done(` function

Comment: I just copied your service and made changes. There are some errors in it, like there was no end brace for the `updateAllEntriesUser` function, which I just added to my answer. Without the full source of `databaseService` I can't tell what the problem is. Also, try changing `factory` to `service` as I did.

Comment: `databaseService` is now without errors and it is the full code which is listed in the question. Why should I use `service` instead of a `factory`? I tried it also, without success.

Comment: `service` creates a singleton object which you don't have to instantiate with `new`, i.e. var service = new databaseService(). You can access the same version of databaseService wherever it's injected. It also can't be the full code because it doesn't end in `])` and would cause a syntax error.

Comment: Post it as it is now with the changes I suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123113/discussion-between-spongessuck-and-d4rty).